# Requests not shown in ngrok web ui when running as a service

Tags: ngrok

I have ngrok setup on my Debian web server and followed the guide [here](https://ngrok.com/docs/guides/device-gateway/linux/#step-4-configure-ngrok-to-recover-on-outages) for setting it up to run as a service. The web ui comes up fine but whenever I make requests to the ngrok url, they don't show up in the web ui. I know that the requests are getting through because the endpoint ngrok is forwarding them to responds accordingly.

My ngrok config is as follows:

```
version: "2"
authtoken: AUTH_TOKEN
web_addr: 192.168.1.11:4041
tunnels:
  website:
    proto: http
    addr: 8000
    domain: CUSTOM-DOMAIN.ngrok-free.app
```

Furthermore, I installed it as a service using the following command:

```
sudo ngrok service install --config /home/USERNAME/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
```

Also, if I stop the service, and start the tunnel from the command line running

```
ngrok start website
```

I can see the requests in the web ui. Something about running ngrok as a service and the web ui shows up but doesn't show any of the requests going through it.